# How to update ArrayList to match user-ordered TreeView

Tags: c#, arraylist, treeview, gtk

I have a `Gtk TreeView` displaying a list of items in an `ArrayList`. The `TreeView` is set to reorderable, so the user can drag and drop items in the list to re-order them.

My question is, how do I update the original `ArrayList` to match the new `TreeView` ordering once reordering has taken place?

Comment: Can you show your code? Is there a specific reason for not using a generic `List<>` instead of the old and redundant `ArrayList`?

Comment: There is no specific reason to use ArrayList over List, but this surely doesn't matter? I am trying to establish how to get the reordered values from the TreeView back into the ArrayList (or List, if you prefer).

Comment: it's probably not causing your issue, but it's only a comment and not an answer anyway. But no one can answer your question without more informations. What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't see any signals you can connect to for this; there is a `rows-reordered` signal in GtkTreeModel but it is documented as not working with drag-and-drop. You may want to consider implementing a custom GtkTreeModel in this case rather than trying to manually synchronize an ArrayList and a GtkListStore; drag-and-drop of rows is [documented](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-GtkTreeView-drag-and-drop.html) as being handled by the GtkTreeDragSource and GtkTreeDragDest interfaces.

Comment: I am able to tell when a user has finished dragging-and-dropping using DragEnd. This is no problem. The issue is in iterating through the GtkTreeModel to recover the items in the order in which they can be seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to come up with a solution - the code below simply prints out all items in the list; hopefully you can see how by doing this you can find the correct index for the items and thus reorder them in the associated ArrayList.

```
        TreeIter iter;
        yourNodeView.Model.GetIterFirst (out iter);
        for (int i = 0; i < yourNodeView.Model.IterNChildren(); i++)
        {
            string result = ((TypeOfListItem)sequencerNodeView.Model.GetValue (iter, 0)).ToString();
            //Here you would add the TypeOfListItem instance to a new ArrayList, and then after the loop swap out the old ArrayList for the new one. 
            Console.WriteLine("print the item "+result);
            yourNodeView.Model.IterNext(ref iter);
        }
```

The TypeOfListItem could of course be any time. I have written a Class called MyListItem which has parameters such as title and description, so that I can access them with:

```
string result = ((MyListItem)sequencerNodeView.Model.GetValue (iter, 0)).title;
```